# Set value to the first day of the month c#

Tags: c#, label

This void will set the value of the label text to the previous month. 
For example: *If today's date is 4/20/2017 the will set the label to 3/20/2017*

What I am want to do is set the label text to first day of the previous month like this: 3/1/2017 
Just not quite sure how to do that.

```
protected void PMonth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Loads the hidden
    if (ViewState["datacountnm"] == null)
    { ViewState["datacountnm"] = 0; }
    ViewState["datacountnm"] = ((int)ViewState["datacountnm"]) - 1;

    lblSelectedDate.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMonths((int)ViewState["datacountnm"]).ToShortDateString();           
}
```

Comment: For completeness, use the linked dupe to get first of current month and then subtract a month from it.

Comment: The second time you enter this code you go back two months, then three and so on. Is this correct?

Comment: `var firstOfMonth = yourDate.AddDays(1-yourDate.Day);`

Comment: Linked dupe was the solution